# Define a variable in Helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I need to define a variable based on an `if` statement and use that variable multiple times.
In order not to repeat the `if` I tried something like this:

```
{{ if condition}}
    {{ $my_val = "http" }}
{{ else }}
    {{ $my_val = "https" }}
{{ end }}
{{ $my_val }}://google.com
```

However this returns an error:

```
Error: render error in "templates/deployment.yaml":
template: templates/deployment.yaml:30:28:
executing "templates/deployment.yaml" at
<include (print $.Template.BasePath "/config.yaml") .>: error calling
include: template: templates/config.yaml:175:59:
executing "templates/config.yaml" at <"https">: undefined variable: $my_val
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The most direct path to this is to use the `ternary` function [provided by the Sprig library](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html).  That would let you write something like

```
{{ $myVal := ternary "http" "https" condition -}}
{{ $myVal }}://google.com
```

A simpler, but more indirect path, is to write a template that generates the value, and calls it

```
{{- define "scheme" -}}
{{- if condition }}http{{ else }}https{{ end }}
{{- end -}}

{{ template "scheme" . }}://google.com
```

If you need to include this in another variable, Helm provides an `include` function that acts just like `template` except that it's an "expression" rather than something that outputs directly.

```
{{- $url := printf "%s://google.com" (include "scheme" .) -}}
```

Comment: Nice solution to that problem, but could you say something about the generic problem of  how variables are scoped? (I want to append values inside a loop to a list I want to use outside that loop.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69425151/207353 is a nice explanation