# Is it possible to define variables use if/else condition in helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

In my values.yaml I have:

```
isLocal: false
localEnv:
  url: abcd
prodEnv:
  url: defg
```

Then I have a service.yaml:

```
{{- if .Values.isLocal }}
{{- $env := .Values.localEnv }}
{{- else}}
{{- $env := .Values.prodEnv }}
{{- end}}
url: {{ $env.url}}
```

Unfortunately I got a 'undefined variable "$env"' error, does anyone have idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[The Go `text/template` documentation](https://godoc.org/text/template) notes:

> A variable's scope extends to the "end" action of the control structure ("if", "with", or "range") in which it is declared....

so your declarations of `$env` go out of scope at the end of the `{{ if }}...{{ end }}` block, which isn't so useful.

Helm also includes (almost all of) a support template library called [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) which [includes](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/defaults.html) a `ternary` function, which acts sort of like an inline "if" statement.  For your example you could write

```
{{- $env := ternary .Values.localEnv .Values.prodEnv .Values.isLocal -}}
```

(Also consider just writing totally separate Helm values files for each environment, and installing your chart with `helm install -f prod.yaml`, instead of trying to encapsulate every possible environment in a single file.)

Comment: It's a good idea to use one Helm values for each environment, but how to deal if we have a commune values between 'prod.yaml ' and 'local.yaml' ?

Comment: You can use multiple `-f` options: `helm install -f common.yaml -f prod.yaml ...`

Comment: Note that if you'll use instead of .Values.prodEnv some expression (i.e.: get .someObject .Values.localEnv # .Values.localEnv contains an attribute name) is will be executed before test expression!

Answer (score 47):

One more way would be to create the variable before starting the `if/else` block. For example:

```golang
{{- $env := .Values.prodEnv -}}
{{ if .Values.isLocal }}
  {{- $env = .Values.localEnv -}}
{{ end}}
```

Notice that I've **not** used the `:=` operator inside the `if` block as the variable is already created.

and then

```golang
url: {{ $env.url}}
```

Comment: Thank you as well!

Comment: I prefer this answer since it more specifically answers the question principle (using if/else blocks, as this could be extended to more complex logic).

Answer (score 15):

You actually can define the variable $env outside the `if` block and assign its value using `=` with `if` block.

```
{{- $env := "" }}
{{- if .Values.isLocal }}
{{- $env = .Values.localEnv }}
{{- else}}
{{- $env = .Values.prodEnv }}
{{- end}}
url: {{ $env.url}}
```

> Please note: `:=` will declare the variable while assigning the value. On the other hand, `=` will assign the value only.
> If you use `:=` in `if`, it will declare a new local variable $env which will not impact the value of $env declared outside the `if` block.