# Get value from list if list-item has key==value

Tags: go, templates, kubernetes-helm, default, go-templates

I have the following yaml

```yaml
items:
   - itemName: a
     awesome: true
   - itemName: b
   - itemName: c
     awesome: false
```

I need a function that gets `a` as an output, since item `a` has the attribute `awesome == true`. **How do I do that?**

Approach that does not work:

```
{{- $result := "nope" }}
{{- range $i := $items }}
  {{- if and (and (hasKey $i. awesome) ($i.awesome)) !($result -eq "nope") }}
    {{- $result := $i.itemName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Have not tried the above approach, but am confident that this does not work (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324405/define-a-variable-in-helm-template)). What I'd need is a default function that works for lists. I could not find any in [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/). Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324405/define-a-variable-in-helm-template), based on which you claim you know that the code doesn't work, does not, in the question snippet, *pre-declare* the variable.

In your code you *do* pre-declare the variable but you are making a different error. The error is that you are using `:=` to assign the value to the pre-declared variable, however `:=` in templates works the same as in Go itself, it initializes a new variable. You need to use `=` for assignment to an existing variable.

https://pkg.go.dev/text/template@go1.17.2#hdr-Variables

> A pipeline inside an action may initialize a variable to capture the
> result. The initialization has syntax
>
> ```
> $variable := pipeline
> ```
>
> where `$variable` is the name of the variable. An
> action that declares a variable produces no output.
>
> Variables previously declared can also be assigned, using the syntax
>
> ```
> $variable = pipeline
> ```

So all you need to do is to change `{{- $result := $i.itemName }}` to `{{- $result = $i.itemName }}`.

```golang
{{- $result := "nope" }}
{{- range $i := $items }}
  {{- if and (and (hasKey $i. awesome) ($i.awesome)) !($result -eq "nope") }}
    {{- $result = $i.itemName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

---

An example to prove this is working: https://play.golang.org/p/A44yl7jo0v7